# How to fix "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin" when using Mailgun's validate API?

Tags: javascript, mailgun

I am adding a custom email field validation function to my landing page created via unbounce, and decided to use Mailgun's validate api to do so. However, I am getting CORS errors.

I have tried

```
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + window.btoa("api:"KEY"));
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "GET");
```

My full code

```
function useMailGun() {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "https://api.mailgun.net/v4/address/validate", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + window.btoa("api:KEY"));
    request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "GET");
    request.withCredentials = true;
    request.onload = function() {
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        let data = JSON.parse(request.response);
        if(data.reason.length > 0) {
          return false;
        }
        else {
          return true;
        }
      }
      else {
        console.error("Failed to load Mailgun's api");
        return false;
      }
    }
    request.onerror = function() {
      console.error("Failed to load Mailgun's api");
      return false
    }
    request.send({
      "address":$("#email").val(),
    });
  }
```

Error message I am getting:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mailgun.net/v4/address/validate' from origin 'website' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: try to add `cors` lib to your project

Answer (score 0):

It's not possbile to make request to Mailgun api when using frontend javascript without using a proxy. See the [documentation](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-js#mailgunjs-):

> If used in the browser, a proxy is required to communicate with
>   the Mailgun api due to cors limitations. Also, do not publish your
>   private api key in frontend code.

You either have to use a proxy or set up a backend service like node-js or php on your own to make a request.

Comment: How would I use a proxy to make a request, and would I have to whitelist the proxy's ip on mailgun? Or are there any email validation apis that work client side?